# Leaflet.js - how to draw only the contiguous 48 states?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet to draw a map of the US (and nothing else). I want to draw only the 48 contiguous states-- no Alaska or Hawaii, no Canada, no Mexico, etc. My goal is to end up with an interactive map that looks like this:

[image]

I know how to do the highlighting of those specific states, etc... I just need to be able to control Leaflet so it doesn't draw anything outside the US. How can I do this?

(I would just use an imagemap over a picture of the US, but I want the states to highlight on hover... if going that route and not using Leaflet is a better way to go about this, I am open to but not sure how to draw the states highlighted on hover and would appreciate any tips.)

*Note: this is different from this question, [Show only United States when using Leaflet.js and OSM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117281/show-only-united-states-when-using-leaflet-js-and-osm), which is asking how to set the bounds on the map so the user can't scroll away from the USA. I want to change what is drawn on the screen.*

Comment: Sounds like Leaflet isn't what you're looking for - Leaflet is only a widget for compositing whatever images are on the tiles you give it into a zoomable canvas. Try looking at something like [D3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)

Answer (score 1):

Grab a GeoJSON file of the states(http://leafletjs.com/examples/us-states.js), slice Alaska and Hawaii off the file(or do it clientside).Bring in these states with `L.geoJSON`. Add text labels with for each state with `L.DivIcon`.