# Show only an area using openlayer and OSM

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I found this Question [Show only United States when using Leaflet.js and OSM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117281/show-only-united-states-when-using-leaflet-js-and-osm) which is exactly what I'm looking for but the problem is I don't use leaflet. Currently using OpenLayers at the moment, saw some example [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/) but no luck any ideas?

```
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([125.126012,6.066714]),
      zoom: 17,
      minZoom: 17,
      maxZoom: 18
    })
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the [view](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html) `extent` property. Note that it restricts the location of the center of the map.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([125.126012,6.066714]),
    zoom: 17,
    minZoom: 17,
    maxZoom: 18,
    extent:ol.proj.transformExtent([113,4, 119, 8], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
  })
});
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot been searching for hours and i can't find anything TQ :)